# Closure of a set's cone

Tags: general-topology, geometry, differential-geometry

working in $\mathbb{R}^3$ , say I'm looking at the set :  $\{1\} \times  S^1$

denote E for the cone of the set above, is E a closed set? 
(I think it is) 
if not, what is it's closure?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

product of closed set is closed set, clearly its complement is open. its closure is itself.

Comment: thanks but, please notice that E is the cone of the defined set http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone_(linear_algebra)